# symfony don't find post data after fetch

Tags: javascript, php, symfony5

I am trying to send post data using fetch in twig. But I can not access to those variables in the controller.

here my fetch

```js
let response = await fetch(baseUrl + '/aaa/nom-de-levenement/add', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token,
            "Content-type": "application/json",
        },

        body: {
            "page": "pageName"
        }
    })
    return response.json()
```

and my controller :

```php
/**
     * @Route("/add", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function createPage($slug, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, EventRepository $eventRepository, Request $request){

        $event = $eventRepository->findOneBy(['slug' => $slug]);

        $data = $request->request->get('page');

        dd($data);
}
```

And the dump returning null

Thank you for help

I tryied to change the content type in fetch dans some things in the controller for exemple :

$_POST return null

$request->get('page') return null

I try the controller using postman, and it return the good variable.

Comment: try to send body as a string in fetch API: `body : JSON.stringfy({page: "pageName"})`. One more point I think you have to adjust the route annotation and include a `slug` there: `@Route("/{slug}/add", methods={"POST"})`.
 And then try `$request->request->get('page', 'default page')`

Comment: Hello thank you for your help. Firstly, slug in configure for the controller in global. I tryied to stringfy the body but I always get the default result.

Comment: What if you update Content-Type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ?

Comment: This gave me an anwer :  ``$this->request->request->all()`` give me : 

```
{
   "page: myPage" : null
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To send POST data that way you should use `FormData` object:

```js
const data = new FormData();
data.append('page', 'pageName');

let response = await fetch(baseUrl + '/aaa/nom-de-levenement/add', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token,
        "Content-type": "application/json",
    },
    body: data
})
return response.json()
```

Then you could do that in your controller:

```php
$data = $request->request->get('page');
```

If you try to pass "raw" data in `body`, you can access it using `$request->getContent()` method, but I believe in this case that will return `"[object Object]"` because the `body` object will be simply parsed to string.